# Excel macro - Copy a path from a cell and paste it into a lookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project in which I need to dynamically generate a file path for a lookup function.  If there is a way for me to upload a file, I have a sample dummy file to illustrate, but here goes:

My workbook has two tabs, Items and Members.  In the items tab, I have a column of identifiers (B), a column of assignees (C), a column where I fetch a file path (D, although not strictly necessary), and then a number of lookup functions that use the path from D (E onward).  My goal is to have a "go button" in each row of column A to activate the macro for that particular row.

| A | B | C | D | E | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Go Button** | **ID** | **Assigned To** | **Path** | **Lookup1** |  |
| Go | 12345 | JAD | =INDEX(Members!$C:$C,MATCH(Items!$C2,Members!$B:$B,0)) | =INDEX('E:\Team\Blue\Individial Files[John Doe Workload.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,MATCH($B2,'E:\Team\Blue\Individial Files[John Doe Workload.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0)) |  |

In the members tab, I have a column of names (A), initials (B), and individual file paths (C).

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Name** | **Initials** | **Path** |
| John Doe | JAD | E:\Team\Blue\Individial Files\[John Doe Workload.xlsx] |

So the challenge is that for each item in the items tab, a member is assigned to work it (via their initials).  Each member has their own individual file containing their workload, from which I'm trying to pull information.  I'm able to fetch the path easily enough, but when it comes to using that path in the lookup functions, I'm stuck.  I realize that the INDIRECT function would work, but the problem is that there are ~50 different individual files, which would all have to be open for INDIRECT to work.  New items are continually coming in, and occasionally the person assigned to an item may change.

My thought is that I can create a macro that will copy the path, then use it to write the lookup function(s) in that row.  Ideally, this macro could be activated for a particular row by clicking the button in column A for that row.

Edit:  Sample of the workload file:

| A | B | C | D | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ID** | **Start Date** | **Due Date** | **Status Code** | ... |
| 12345 | 10/10/2022 | 11/1/2022 | A2 | ... |

Comment: what have you done so far for the macro?

Comment: Nothing yet.  I'm completely new to VBA.

Comment: you can try creating a string for path.
and combine variables so you can make it dynamic.
something like this

 aPath = Sheet1.Range("D" & j).Value
    bPath = "=INDEX('" & aPath & "Sheet8'!$B:$B,MATCH($B" & j & ",'" & aPath & "Sheet8'!$A:$A,0))"

and  do a loop.


can you post  a sample data that you are trying to lookup so I  can replicate it?
the John Doe Workload Sheet it  needs to check.

Comment: Sure.  Edited the post to add it.

Comment: and the E3 should show  the  Start Date?
all the path is this"E:\Team\Blue\Individial Files\" right

Comment: Correct on both counts

Comment: and sheet1 should look like this?
<img>https://i.imgur.com/jeHfK2P.png

Comment: Yeah that looks like what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did on my end to make the Items Sheet look like this.
[image]

and my Members Sheet is

[image]

```
Sub SampleCode()
Dim aPath As String
Dim bPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

    With Sheet1
        i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' to check the row count on Items sheet
        .Range("D2:D" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,Members!B:C,2,0)" 'to check the path from Members sheet
        .Range("D2:D" & i).Value = .Range("D2:D" & i).Value 'to make it a value so it wont always compute since its a formula
    
        j = 2 'we  start at row 2 since row 1 is header
        Do Until j > i ' meaning from 2 until the last row count
            aPath = .Range("D" & j).Value 'a string to get Path value.
            bPath = "=VLOOKUP(B" & j & ",'" & aPath & "Sheet1'!$A:$D,2,0)" 'I used vlookup instead
            .Range("E" & j).Formula = bPath 'placing the formula  for each Lookup1 cells Column E
            .Range("E" & j).Value = .Range("E" & j).Value 'again making as text not formula
            j = j + 1 'proceed to next row
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

I used Vlookup instead of Index Match.

Comment: Ok this looks awesome!  One question - is there a way to make it activate on a per-row basis, instead of looping through all of them?  The problem is that the real spreadsheet I'm working on has several thousand rows, and not all of them are going to change at the same time.

Comment: you can create a helper cell with 1s and 0s, then create an if else condition.

Comment: Hmm.  That could work.  Especially if I automate the helper cell to detect a change in the row. Thanks!